# Multiple conditions in a single query Mysql?

Tags: mysql

**Table Name: `Price`**

```
City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      3000        60      13-07-2014
Delhi       4000        50      14-04-2014
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014
Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014
Mumbai      2500        54      19-08-2014
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014
Bangalore   1700        44      02-03-2014
```

Expected Output will be ;

```
City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014
```

I need query for getting this output

can anyone help me out of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want your results to be fetched on the basis of minimum Gold_Rates,hence query is

```
select City,min(Gold_Rate),Silver_rate,Date from Price  group by City;
```

and if you want to fetch the result on the basis of latest date then try this,

```
select City,Gold_Rate,Silver_Rate,max(Date) from Price group by City;
```

and according to the requirements you mentioned in the comments,to be more precisely you will use this 
`Select city, gold_rate, silver_rate,date from price where Date in (select max(Date) from price group by city);`

Comment: This query working but it shows only the maximum date..but i need the recode which is relevant to the maximun date for each city..How can i write for this scenario

Comment: My expected output is like,

Comment: City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)

Comment: please clarify,do you want your results on the basis of recent date?The following query is i think what you are looking for,i mentioned it in the answer too

Comment: select City,Gold_Rate,Silver_Rate,max(Date) from Price group by City;

Comment: This query shows the record of max(date) but it shows wrong "gold rate" and "silver rate" values..that is it shows only maximum date but not relevant to the max(date) values for unique city names...

Comment: by executing your query gives the output like City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      3000       60      18-09-2014
Delhi           4000       50      01-10-2014
Bangalore  1400        40      16-06-2014

Comment: try this and tell me if this works : select City,Gold_Rate,Silver_Rate,max(Date) from Price group by City having Date=MAX(Date);

Comment: no dude it also not working...it saying that "unknown column name in having clause"

Comment: Ok my dude, try this,

Comment: Select city, gold_rate, silver_rate,date from price where Date in (select max(Date) from price group by city);

Comment: Ya thanks dude its working..but little bit trouble in that querry..am using MySql db, in that the date column having both date and time values..ur query does not fetch the maximum date and time values

Comment: for example: consider these two values in date column 1. 22-01-2014 12:55:25, 2. 22-01-2014 11:45:24, for this input it should display the recent date that is 22-01-2014 12:55:25

Answer (score 0):

`select City,Gold_Rate,Silver_Rate,max(Date) from Price group by City`

Try this query.

Comment: City        Gold_Rate   Silver_Rate Date

Mumbai      1500        58      18-09-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)
Delhi       1800        60      01-10-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)
Bangalore   1400        40      16-06-2014 (record of the maximun/recent date)

Comment: I need that output only dude... That is the record of the maximum date to be displayed for the unique city

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from price where gold_rate = (select min(gold_rate) from price p where p.city = price.city);
```

or you can make it use of inner joins

```
select * from price inner join (
    select min(gold_rate) gold_rate, city
    from price
    group by city
  ) as ip on ip.city = price.city and ip.gold_rate = price.gold_rate
```

Both will give you the required output.
Good day